# Android load SharedPreferences for widget into Preference Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am able to link an shared preference to an activity that way:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
 if (extras != null) appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                                                 AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

 if (appWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) finish();

 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Widget"+appWidgetId, 0);
```

In the configuration dialog of my preference application I can access the displayed preferences via:

```
 getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
```

These preferences are not linked to a widget but global. How can I change the preferences that are displayed in my preference activity to the widget aligned preferences?

I tried to set the shared preference file manually:

```
  PreferenceManager localPrefs = getPreferenceManager();
  localPrefs.setSharedPreferencesName("GITC_Prefs");
```

This leads to a null pointer exception when I try to access the shared Preferences via

```
 PreferenceActivity.getPreferenceScreen();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access same `SharedPreferences` in two activities you need to specify same name for `PreferencesActivity.getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(name)` and `Activity.getSharedPreferences(name, 0)`. You currently specify **"Widget" + appWidgetId** in the first case and **"GITC_Prefs"** in the second.